# How to convert an LSP into objectarx C# to close Autocad polylines?

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin, objectarx

I need to create a C# objectarx function that will check if a polyline is connected and open.  If so then close they polyline.  This sample code cannot be used because this will not check if it is connected:

```
if (polyline.Closed == false)
{
    // Close polyline
    polyline.Closed = true;
}
```

I found out how to do it but it is in LISP.  Does anyone know how to convert this to C# objectarx .net?

```
;;  PLsCloseCorners.lsp [command name: PLsCL for PolyLines CLose]
;;  To Close all open lightweight Polylines, with the start/end
;;  vertex at the [apparent] intersection of the starting and
;;  ending segments, without coincident start/end vertices.
;;  If one "looks" closed (i.e. last vertex coincides with first one),
;;  but is not closed in Polyline terms, this will close it from
;;  the next-to-last vertex, not by adding a zero-length segment.
;;  [If beginning and/or ending Polyline segment is/are arcs, and
;;  start/end vertices are not coincident, will locate new corner
;;  as if endpoints of arc(s) are endpoints of line segment(s);
;;  if ending segment is an arc and start/end vertices are not
;;  coincident, will alter arc's path.]
;;  Kent Cooper, July 2009
;;
(defun C:PLsCL (/ plset pl plverts corner)
  (setq cmde (getvar 'cmdecho))
  (setvar 'cmdecho 0)
  (command "_.undo" "_begin")
  (setq plset (ssget "X" '((0 . "LWPOLYLINE"))))
    ; omit the "X" from the above line to let User select them
  (while (> (sslength plset) 0)
    (setq pl (ssname plset 0))
    (if (not (vlax-curve-isclosed pl))
      (progn
        (setq
          plverts (cdr (assoc 90 (entget pl))); number of vertices
          corner
            (inters 
              (vlax-curve-getStartPoint pl)
              (vlax-curve-getPointAtParam pl 1)
              (vlax-curve-getPointAtParam pl (1- plverts))
              (vlax-curve-getPointAtParam pl (- plverts 2))
              nil
            ); end inters & corner
        ); end setq
        (command
          "_.pedit"
          pl
          "_edit"
          "_move"
          corner
        ); end command
        (repeat (- plverts 2)
          (command "_next"); move to next-to-last vertex
        ); end repeat
        (command
          "_break"
          "_next"
          "_go"
          "_eXit"
          "_close"
          ""
        ); end command
      ); end progn
    ); end if
    (ssdel (ssname plset 0) plset)
  ); end while
  (command "_.undo" "_end")
  (setvar 'cmdecho cmde)
  (princ)
); end defun
```

### Update #1

What I am actually trying to do is determine if a polyline should be closed.  Picture a polyline shaped as the letter C and another polyline as the letter O. In this case, I would like to close the one shaped as the letter O.

Example:

```
public bool IsPolylineConnected(Polyline pline)
{

  // Convert the code from the LSP to C#
  // A polyline with the shape of the letter C would return false
  // A polyline with the shape of the letter O would return true

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a test drawing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you cast the polyline as a curve object you can check if the start point and end point are the same.

Casting the polyline as a curve saves you the trouble of dealing with the different polyline types.

Comment: Miir, I am trying to convert the above code from LSP to C# (ObjectArx).  If you have the actual code on how to do this please let me know!  Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a test drawing ?
And, if you really want to use the logic in lisp, you can always call LISP function from .NET.

For example you have lisp function

```
;(defun DoIt()

;Define the Lisp function as a command using c:
(defun c:DoIt()

    (setq    pntA (getpoint "\nPick A")
            pntB (getpoint pntA "\nPick B")
    )
    (grdraw pntA pntB 1 2)

)
```

C#:

```
[CommandMethod("DoIt", CommandFlags.Session)]
public void DoItMethod()
{
DocumentCollection acDocMgr = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager;
Document acDoc = acDocMgr.Open(@"C:\SampleDrawings\Lights.dwg", false);
using (DocumentLock dl = acDoc.LockDocument())
{
Editor ed = acDoc.Editor;
using (ResultBuffer rb = new ResultBuffer())
{
rb.Add(new TypedValue((int)LispDataType.Text, "c:DoIt"));
ResultBuffer rbRes = Application.Invoke(rb);
if (rbRes != null)
{
TypedValue[] tvalues = rbRes.AsArray();
foreach (TypedValue tv in tvalues)
ed.WriteMessage("\n" + tv.ToString());
rbRes.Dispose();
}
else
ed.WriteMessage("\n Result buffer is null.");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Madhukar, very nice post!  But I would actually like to convert the code to C# instead of calling LISP code.  Thank you.